# Gradle plugin Integration With Eclipse

Tags: gradle

Am trying to add gradle plugin to eclipse juno

Following the procedure in eclipse Help-install new software

but when am trying to add below url am getting error message unable to read repository

link used

http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle (latest release)

can anyone please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Tip:** Maybe time to update Eclipse before adding Gradle*

See the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/gradle), as there are multiple plug-ins which add Gradle support.

The official [Gradle for Eclipse](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) is on the [marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration) as well.

Comment: @SanthoshChandrashekar you're welcome to accept the answer